# Problema login con php y mysql

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, ajax

Tengo un problema con una tarea para la universidad, sucede que cuando me trato de loguearme en una página hecha por mí, el sistema me permite acceder únicamente teniendo la contraseña o el usuario correcto, cuando en realidad ambos campos deberían ser correctos para permitirme el acceso.
Este es el código de mi página HTML

```
<html>
        <head>
             <title>Login</title>
             <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
             <script src="validarLogin.js"></script>
        </head>

        <body>
             <form name = "forma01">
             <h1>Login</h1>
             <label class="etiqueta">
                Correo Electronico:
                <input id="user" type="email" name="user"/>
             </label>
             <br>
             <label class="etiqueta">
                Password:
                <input id = "password" type="password" name = "password"/>
             </label>
             <br>
             <input type="submit" value="Login" onclick="logear(); return false;"/>
             <input type="reset" value="Limpiar">
             </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Este es el de mi función con ajax:

```
function logear()
{
    var user = $('#user').val();
    var pass = $('#password').val();

    if(user == "" || pass == "")
    {
         alert("Campos incompletos");
    }
    else
    {  
        $.ajax({
            url         : 'validarUsuario.php?user='+user+'&pass='+pass,
            type        : "post",
            dataType    : "text",
            success     : function(res)
            {
                if(res != 0)
                {
                    window.location.href = "lista-administradores.php";         
                }
                else
                {
                    alert("Datos incorrectos");
                }
            }, error: function()
            {
                alert("Error al conectar al servidor");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Y el de mi método con php:

```
<?php
require "conecta.php";
$con = conecta();
$user = $_REQUEST['user'];
$pass = $_REQUEST['pass'];
$res = 0;
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM administradores
        WHERE status = 1 AND eliminado = 0 AND pass = $pass AND correo = '".$user."'";

$res = mysql_query($sql, $con);

echo $res;
?>
```

Por favor, estoy desesperado, pues se entrega mañana.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT *
        FROM administradores
        WHERE status = 1 AND eliminado = 0 AND pass = '".$pass."' AND correo = '".$user."'";
```

Verifica que estes concatenado bien las variables, al parecer $pass no lo estas pasando correctamente.

Intenta debuggear la variable `"$sql"`, para verificar si la query se esta generando correctamente.

Comment: Además de que no tiene concatenado, declara una variable para un método como `mysql_query` en  ` $res = 0` y es un función obsoleta que devuelve `FALSE` o `TRUE`. Aconsejaría cambiar o a `mysqli` o `PDO`